# Assistance with Cleaning Data Scraping Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and I was wondering what would be the best way to clean the output of the code. This is what I have so far:

```
# DNH KDR Checker

import time
import urllib.request
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

print("Please Enter SteamID64")
player = input()

dnh = 'https://pug.districtnine.host/profile?id=' + str(player)
page = urllib.request.urlopen(dnh)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

kdr_value = soup.find(class_="col-md-3")

print(kdr_value.prettify())
```

When I enter a Steam64ID (In this case, 76561198802827420) The Output Comes out like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 <h4>
  <i class="fas fa-crosshairs">
  </i>
  Kills: 1717
 </h4>
 <h4>
  <i class="fas fa-skull">
  </i>
  deaths:
  <strong>
   1462
  </strong>
  <br/>
 </h4>
 <h4>
  <i class="fas fa-dot-circle">
  </i>
  kdr: 1.17
  <br/>
 </h4>
</div>
```

But I want it to come out like this:

```
Kills: 1717
Deaths: 1462
KDR: 1.17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple. To remove HTML markup, use `BeautifulSoup`'s [get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) function.

In the last line replace your print statement by this:

```
print(kdr_value.get_text())
```

Now, you'll get the output as:

```
Kills: 1717
deaths: 1462
kdr: 1.17
```

Comment: omfg I can't believe it was that simple and I missed it. I'm kicking myself for that one haha. Thanks!